# Boost Graph edge comparison not working

Tags: c++, boost, graph, boost-graph

I'm trying to do some statistics with graphs (comparing 2 graphs). But have a problem when I compare the edges.

So, I create two graphs with some edges and then some templates for the vertices and edges operations.  For the vertices it's working apperently well, but for the edges it's not working properly.

```
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/reverse_graph.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/iteration_macros.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/graph_utility.hpp>
typedef boost::adjacency_list < boost::vecS, boost::vecS,
                            boost::undirectedS > Graph;

template <typename T> std::set<T> operator-(const std::set<T>& a,
                                            const std::set<T>& b)
{
    std::set<T> r;
    std::set_difference(
                        a.begin(), a.end(),
                        b.begin(), b.end(),
                        std::inserter(r, r.end()));

    return r;
}

template <typename T> std::set<T> operator/(const std::set<T>& a,
                                            const std::set<T>& b)
{
    std::set<T> r;
    std::set_intersection(
                          a.begin(), a.end(),
                          b.begin(), b.end(),
                          std::inserter(r, r.end()));

    return r;
}



void compare(const Graph& a, const Graph& b)
{
    std::set<Graph::vertex_descriptor > av, bv, samev, extrav, missingv;
    std::set<Graph::edge_descriptor> ae, be, re, samee, extrae, missinge;

    BGL_FORALL_VERTICES_T(v, a, Graph) av.insert(v);
    BGL_FORALL_VERTICES_T(v, b, Graph) bv.insert(v);
    samev    = (av / bv);
    extrav   = (bv - av);
    missingv = (av - bv);


    BGL_FORALL_EDGES_T(e, a, Graph) ae.insert(e);
    BGL_FORALL_EDGES_T(e, b, Graph) be.insert(e);

    samee    = (ae / be);
    extrae   = (be - ae);
    missinge = (ae - be);

    // TODO(silgon): reverse_graph
    // boost::reverse_graph<Graph> r(b);
    // BGL_FORALL_EDGES_T(e, r, Graph) re.insert(e);
    std::cout << "---- Vertices ----\n"
              << "same: " << samev.size() << std::endl
              << "extra: " << extrav.size() << std::endl
              << "missing: " << missingv.size() << std::endl;

    std::cout << "---- Edges ----\n"
              << "same: " << samee.size() << std::endl
              << "extra: " << extrae.size() << std::endl
              << "missing: " << missinge.size() << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    Graph a;
    {
        boost::graph_traits<Graph>::vertex_descriptor v, u, y;
        u = boost::vertex(1, a);
        v = boost::vertex(2, a);
        y = boost::vertex(3, a);
        boost::add_edge(u, v, a);
    }
    Graph b;
    {
        boost::graph_traits<Graph>::vertex_descriptor v, u, y;
        u = vertex(1, b);
        v = vertex(2, b);
        y = vertex(3, b);
        boost::add_edge(u, v, b);
        boost::add_edge(y, v, b);
    }

    const char* name = "123456";
    std::cout << "---Graph1---" << "\n";
    boost::print_graph(a);
    std::cout << "Edges: ";
    boost::print_edges(a,name);
    std::cout << "---Graph2---" << "\n";
    boost::print_graph(b);
    std::cout << "Edges: ";
    boost::print_edges(b,name);

    compare(a,b);
}
```

As for the result of the program it's the following:

```
---Graph1---
0 <--> 
1 <--> 2 
2 <--> 1 
Edges: (2,3) 
---Graph2---
0 <--> 
1 <--> 2 
2 <--> 1 3 
3 <--> 2 
Edges: (2,3) (4,3) 
---- Vertices ----
same: 3
extra: 1
missing: 0
---- Edges ----
same: 0
extra: 2
missing: 1
```

You can see that one of the edges is the same (2,3), but when doing the operations it's not taking it into account so in the results it say same:0, and either extra or missing results are not working.

Comment: What is your exact typedef for `Graph`, i.e. what kind of graph representation do you use? This influences the actual type used for `edge_descriptor` and what an `edge_descriptor` stores. I suspect that it isn't simply a pair of `vertex_descriptors` in your case, and therefore not necessarily comparable across graphs.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to put it in the code. I also have the code here: https://ideone.com/D1Gk1w

Comment: By the way, I just checked with undirected and directed graph and it's the same result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a temporary solution to my problem, instead of:

```
std::set<Graph::edge_descriptor> ae
BGL_FORALL_EDGES_T(e, a, Graph) ae.insert(e)
```

I did the following code for edges.

```
std::set<std::pair<unsigned long, unsigned long> > ae;
BGL_FORALL_EDGES_T(e, ga, Graph) gae.insert(std::make_pair(e.m_source, 
                                                           e.m_target));
```

The problem is that the edges of boost graph have the "m_eproperty" which I don't really know why is there, and it contains values like `0x125d0c0`. Then I created a pair based on the source and the target of an edge and then I evaluated the same way as above (with the templates).

Answer (score 4):

Digging into Boost's `edge_descriptor` implementation (in `boost/graph/detail/edge.hpp`, we find that every edge descriptor stores the source and target `vertex_descriptor`s, but also a pointer to an edge property.  This pointer is different for the two edges whose `vertex_descriptor`s are otherwise identical.

This means that you need to define your own `edge_descriptor` comparator which you use for your `std::set`s and for the `set_intersection`/`set_difference` operations, e.g. like this:

```
struct edge_cmp
{
  bool operator () (const Graph::edge_descriptor& a, const Graph::edge_descriptor& b) const
  {
    if (a.m_source < b.m_source) { return true; }
    if (a.m_source > b.m_source) { return false; }
    return (a.m_target < b.m_target);
  }
};
```

A comparator object of this type must be passed to all the sets you construct, and to the intersection/difference calls.

[I've forked your code on ideone](https://ideone.com/yxwiGz) and modified it accordingly. The output:

```
---- Vertices ----
same: 3
extra: 1
missing: 0
---- Edges ----
same: 1
extra: 1
missing: 0
```